# How to expand and close navbar mobile with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that the script doesn't perform the task I want.

I need a script that will add Class "active" in an ul with id "btnMob0"

at the moment, it is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('btnMob').click(function(){
                $('btnMob0').addClass('active');
            });
        })
    </script>
```

but, this is not working and has no debugging error

CSS:

```
.active{
        display: block !important;
    }
```

Html:

```
<!-- menu mobile -->
<nav class="menuMobile">
    <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fas btnMob fa-align-justify"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="btnMob0">
      <li class=""><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'home')?>" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" class="nav-link">ENCOMENDAS</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" class="nav-link">CURSOS</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" class="nav-link">VIDEOAULAS</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" class="nav-link">BOLO NO POTE</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTATO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem you need a hashtag "#" in front of the id's try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnMob').click(function(){
      $('#btnMob0').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: então, ja tentei de vários modos, incluindo colocar como id e como class, também utilizei a função on("click") e nenhuma dessas maneiras resolve, o que pode ser?

Comment: obs: outros scripts no mesmo código funcionam normalmente